# what is the way to draw QStyleOptionButton QStyle::CE_CheckBox background?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get the parent background and set it as the checkbox background color. I have this paint method that drows the checkbox:

```
void paint( QPainter* painter,
            const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
            const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // Get item data
    bool value = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toBool();
    QString text = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

    // Fill style options with item data
    const QStyle *style = QApplication::style();
    QStyleOptionButton opt;
    opt.state |= value ? QStyle::State_On : QStyle::State_Off;
    opt.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
    opt.text = text;
    opt.rect = option.rect;

    // Draw item data as CheckBox
    style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_CheckBox,&opt,painter);
}
```

but how do I set the background color of this checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
painter->fillRect(rect, color);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution and put it in the context of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may add codes before drawControl:

```
if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected && option.state & QStyle::State_Active)
    painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());
else if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
    painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.background());
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update:**

You could instead try to init the QStyleOptionButton from the widget, this way you will get the palette of the widget.

```
QStyleOptionButton opt;
opt.initFrom(this);
```

**Old suggestion:**

Changing opt.backgroundBrush might work:

```
opt.backgroundBrush = QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 102));
```

or setting opt.backgroundColor

Comment: error C2039: 'backgroundBrush' : is not a member of 'QStyleOptionButton'
error C2039: 'backgroundColor' : is not a member of 'QStyleOptionButton'

Comment: thanks but still not good :
error C2664: 'QStyleOption::initFrom' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const CheckBoxListDelegate *const ' to 'const QWidget *'